# Is it possible to have email confirmation sent securely to user from a mobile app without having any backend of my own?

Tags: javascript, email, react-native, sendgrid, mailgun

I have an mobile app (React-Native) that has no backend at all. The user does input an email into the app. Is it possible for the app to send an email to that email address without having to contact any backend of my own?

- From what I understood, services like Sendgrid would require that I create one account, and save the credentials of that account on each mobile app, so that the app could send the email using SendGrid's API.
- However, it would not be secure to save the credentials like that on the client.

Is it possible to do this in a secure way?

Comment: No. It's not possible.

Comment: `without having to contact any backend of my own` you would have to use a third party service. You can have the app generate the email contents and meta information but there is no way to send the email from within the app without passing through some mail service.

Comment: Can you just use the device's native mail with a wrapper like [react-native-mail](https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-mail)?

Comment: @kwishnu I suppose we could yes, but we want it to be an automated sending of the email with no user interaction.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I thought so :/